# Printing page without wide margins

Tags: html, css, printing

I have spent several hours of trial and error and Googling this issue. This page views correctly on screen, but when I try to print it, the margins are too wide and the invoice collapses on itself. How do I make the left and right margins smaller when printing?

1. The @page directive is completely ignored.
2. The styles for media="print" are completely ignored.

UPDATE: It does not seem to be an issue of margins per se, but that the width of "container" is significantly smaller than the page I am printing on (US letter).

I won't post all the variations I've tried, but this page does not print correctly in Firefox:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Invoice</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css">
        <style>
        @page {
            margin: 15mm 25mm !important;
            .container {
                width:100%;
                padding-left: 0px;
                padding-right: 0px;
            }
        }
        </style>
        <style type="text/css" media="print"> body { margin:0px; } .container {width:100%;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header text-center">
                    Invoice
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row mb-4">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <img src="/images/logo-for-website.png" width="150px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <b><div>Partaker App Project</div>
                            <div>123 Easter Ln</div>
                            <div>Centennial CO 80111</div></b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div>Date: 3/2/2022</div>
                            <div>Invoice # 68</div>
                            <div>Due date: 6/16/2022</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row mb-4">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <h6 class="mb-3">Bill to:</h6>
                            <div>
                                <strong>Client at ASU</strong>
                            </div>
                            <div>Attn: Hermon Johnson</div>
                            <div>United States  <br />  </div>
                            <div>Tempe, AZ 80222</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <h6 class="mb-3">Ship to:</h6>
                            <div>
                                <strong>Client at ASU</strong>
                            </div>
                            <div>Super Admin</div>
                            <div>United States  <br />  </div>
                            <div>Denver, Denver 80222</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-responsive-sm">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="82%">Item Description</th>
                                    <th width="18%" class="text-right" style="padding-right:20px;">Amount</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                                                                                                                                <tr>
                                            <td class="left strong">App setup - 100 users</td>
                                            <td  class="text-right" style="padding-right:20px;">$0.00</td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                <tr>
                                            <td class="left strong">Annual subscription - 100 users &mdash; June 23, 2022 &ndash; June 23, 2023</td>
                                            <td  class="text-right" style="padding-right:20px;">$58.00</td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                                                                                                            <tr>
                                        <td class="left strong">
                                        &nbsp;<br>
                                        Please mail a check to the address above or pay online here: <br>
                                        <a target="_blank" href="https://melio.me/appproject">https://melio.me/appproject</a>
                                        <br>
                                        Please indicate the invoice number when making your payment.
                                        &nbsp;<br>
                                        &nbsp;<br>
                                        If paying by Melio, please allow 5 business days for your payment to reflect in your account.<br>
                                        If paying by check, please allow 10 business days for your payment to reflect in your account.
                                        &nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>
                                        </td>
                                        <td  class="text-right" style="padding-right:20px;"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                                                                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-right">
                                        <h4><b>Total</b></h4>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-right" style="padding-right:20px;"><h6><b>$58.00</b></h6></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And if my in-page style is this, it still does not work. I'm using the current version of Firefox in Windows 11.

```
        <style>
        @media print {

          body {
            margin: 0;
            padding:0;
          }
          
          .container{
              margin:0;
              padding:0;
              width:191mm !important;
          }
        }
        @page {
            size: 8.5in 11in;
            margin: 15mm 25mm !important;
        }
        </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The inside of an `@page` block should include **paper sizing** - not margins or constraints.

Try replacing:

`margin: 15mm 25mm !important;`

with:

`size: 8.5in 11in;`

*(or whatever size paper you want).*

Then check your print preview and you should see your reduced margins.

You can also remove the `.container` styles inside of your `@page` block.

---

**!! UPDATE - FIREFOX USERS !!**

`@page` and Firefox don't get along (most descriptors). You can remove all of your current print styles and paste in the following:

```
    <style>
      @media print {
        .container {
          padding-left: unset !important;
          padding-right: unset !important;
          max-width: unset !important;
        }
      }
    </style>
```

This will negate default grid styling of the container class.

You can also play with things like NEGATIVE left and right margins to get even wider.

**IMPORTANT** - you'll also want to go into your print settings for Firefox and change margins to "none." Otherwise it'll override these CSS settings.

[image: My print preview in Firefox:]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the exact same result. I suspect it may be browser dependent. I'm using current version of Firefox under Windows 11. Is there a CSS rule that applies to Firefox as well?

Comment: Also, in the print preview shared above, the columns are stacked on top of one another rather than being side by side. Maybe there are other issues going on too, but that prints a one-page invoice on two pages.

Comment: @MrMoxy I updated my original answer for Firefox - give it a look! Also, don't sweat my print preview column vs. row thing - I wasn't properly sourcing your assets or styles. Best of luck to you, and please ...nudge nudge... upvote my answer if it works for you! Cheers!

Comment: Chris, thanks for the Firefox update. That works!

Comment: Woot! Thanks for the followup, @MrMoxy. Glad to hear it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution (unless somebody has a better one).

1. I got rid of the Bootstrap "Container" style which seems to be the source of the problem and replaced it with my own "Invoice" style.
2. I combined the columns with the logo & address and floated the image left.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Invoice</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css">
        <style>
        @media screen {
            #invoice {
              width: 100%;
              padding-right: 15px;
              padding-left: 15px;
              margin-top: 20px;
              margin-right: auto;
              margin-left: auto;
              max-width:1140px;
            }
        }
        @media print {
            #invoice {
              width: 100%;
              padding-right: 15px;
              padding-left: 15px;
              margin-right: 0;
              margin-left: 0;
            }

            body {
            margin: 0;
            padding:0;
            }

            .container{
              margin:0;
              padding:0;
              width:191mm !important;
            }
        }
        @page {
            size: 8.5in 11in;
            margin: 15mm 20mm !important;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="invoice">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header text-center">
                    Invoice
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row sm-4">
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <img src="/images/logo-for-website.png" width="150px" style="float:left;">
                            <b><div>App Project</div>
                            <div>123 Easter Ln</div>
                            <div>Centennial CO 80111</div></b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div>Date: 3/2/2022</div>
                            <div>Invoice # 68</div>
                            <div>Due date: 6/16/2022</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row sm-4">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <h6 class="sm-3">Bill to:</h6>
                            <div>
                                <strong>Client at ASU</strong>
                            </div>
                            <div>Attn: Hermon Johnson</div>
                            <div>United States  <br />  </div>
                            <div>Tempe, AZ 80222</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <h6 class="sm-3">Ship to:</h6>
                            <div>
                                <strong>Client at ASU</strong>
                            </div>
                            <div>Super Admin</div>
                            <div>United States  <br />  </div>
                            <div>Denver, Denver 80222</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-responsive-sm">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="82%">Item Description</th>
                                    <th width="18%" class="text-right" style="padding-right:20px;">Amount</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left strong">App setup - 100 users</td>
                                    <td  class="text-right" style="padding-right:20px;">$0.00</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left strong">Annual subscription - 100 users &mdash; June 23, 2022 &ndash; June 23, 2023</td>
                                    <td  class="text-right" style="padding-right:20px;">$58.00</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left strong">
                                    &nbsp;<br>
                                    Please mail a check to the address above or pay online here: <br>
                                    <a target="_blank" href="https://melio.me/appproject">https://melio.me/appproject</a>
                                    <br>
                                    Please indicate the invoice number when making your payment.
                                    &nbsp;<br>
                                    &nbsp;<br>
                                    If paying by Melio, please allow 5 business days for your payment to reflect in your account.<br>
                                    If paying by check, please allow 10 business days for your payment to reflect in your account.
                                    &nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td  class="text-right" style="padding-right:20px;"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-right">
                                        <h4><b>Total</b></h4>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-right" style="padding-right:20px;"><h6><b>$58.00</b></h6></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```